# Why do I need the Widget instance assigned to a variable in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

All I am doing here is creating a custom widget inheriting the default behaviour of `QWidget`.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class CustomWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setUI()

    def setUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300,300,0,0)
        self.setWindowTitle('CustomWidget')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))

        self.show()
```

Then comes the part of creating instance. When I initialize and run with  following snippet, the widget isn't visible to me.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    CustomWidget() <----------------------This line creates the problem
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However,

```
somevalue = CustomWidget()
```

And,

```
_ = CustomWidget()
```

My question is, why PyQt is showing this behavior? Why I have to assign the instance to some variable even if I don't use it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is python's [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting).

As soon as an object has no no more references to it (assigning it to a variable counts as a reference), it gets deleted by the interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because if you don't store a reference to an object, it is discarded and its memory released for reuse immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.